# Cron - Check if enabled on boot

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a script and configuration file.

- Configuration file contains information about if script will run or not (enabled or disabled).
- If enabled, script must run in predetermined intervals.

I can write a cron job to run script in preset intervals and when script runs I can read the config file and if it is not enabled then I can exit.

However, I'm looking a more convenient way to do this. Is there any way to tell the cron's itself that this job is not activated in boot time? So cron will not start the job if it's not enabled (or the otherwise). Or is it possible to enable/disable job in runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us details as to what yr criterion is for the cron job to run, i.e. to enable the script at boot.

Comment: I quite don't understand, what do you mean by criterion? Basically I'm trying to find a way to tell the cron that the job is enabled or not in boot time without adding/removing anything to/from crontab.

Comment: On what is yr decision to enable that cron job based ? On what should enablement of the job be based ?

Comment: Actually I'm asking that :) I have a configuration file with a parameter like **scriptEnabled=true(or false)** . And also I have added the job inside the crontab (**\*/5 * * * * * /home/linux/test.sh**). How can I make the cron check config file to find out if test.sh job is enabled in configuration file? Or is it possible? Or can you suggest any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, now I undersand! That's a fairly common request:

All you need is to test for the existence of a given file, not its content.
E.g. if you want to run the cron job, create a file say in yr home directory: `$ touch /home/you/cronjob_enable`.

Then edit yr user crontab:

```
$ crontab -e
*/5 * * * *  /bin/bash -c 'test -e /home/you/cronjob_enable && /home/linux/test.sh'
```

That's it. As long as the file is there (empty or not, it's irrelevant) and you have permission to run `/home/linux/test.sh`, the script `test.sh` will run. 
When you erase the file `/home/you/cronjob_enable`, the script test.sh will not be executed.

Comment: Not a straight solution but f...king awesome, flex, customizable workaround! Thanks!

Comment: @BenSen: :-D !!  Good luck with all. Don't hesitate to ask more in the future, but also check such other StackExchange sites as "Unix & Linux", "Stack Overflow", etc... They also constitute a great knowledge base for this type of query.

Comment: Unfortunately I noticed that it would be better idea to post this on UNIX & Linux as you suggested after I posted the question. But thanks for the help and the tips !